# Eventbrite api for recommending events

Tags: recommendation-engine, eventbrite

I would like to know if eventbrite api provides recommendation services too.If not, is it possible to implement it with the help of the other data the api provides?

Answer (score 0):

Eventbrite does not currently offer a public API to their recommendation system.  However, all of their public event content is available via their [event_search()](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/) API method.  You might be able to build your own recommendations based on that data.